# Pascal reading a line of text into separate strings

Tags: string, text, pascal, freepascal

Basically a line looks like this: 'number number text text text' with spaces dividing them. The numbers are ok, because the readln() just splits them after the space, but it reads the 3 texts as one. How can i read them into separate strings?

Comment: You probably meant that you used **read()** instead of readln(). readln() always reads until the end of the line (also for numbers). Unfortunately for you read() for a string also reads to the end of the line (unlike for numbers). So the only solution for you would be to split the text once you read it, in code.

Comment: You can use [sscanf](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/sscanf.html) function from SysUtils unit. Just read whole line using `ReadLn` and then split it to the variables using `sscanf`.

Comment: More Pascal like is to use TStringList.delimtedtext

Comment: @Rik Yeah, I read the whole file char by char and split it at spaces, but it was a really long code and I wanted to do it more effectively (this is for an exam haha)

Comment: @Abelisto Thank you, I'll try both and see which one works for me c:

Comment: @Marco_van_de_Voort (I'm just guessing you use _ in usernames, I'm new here) ^

Comment: @LeventeSzabó Spaces can be left out when replying to a user. You can also press the @-sign and the first few letters from the username and press tab to choose the username. The name will automatically be filled in.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody faces this problem, here's a really easy solution I just found: read the whole thing into a string. Then pos(' ',stringsname), then copy('spacepos'+1, 200), then delete(spacepos,200) from the first string and voilá.